# Resequencing of workflow events

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Looking for suggestion or solution on the following usecase

1. Application receives messages ordered by change time identified by a
   functional key (e.g. employee id). There can be multiple messages
   for a functional key
2. Each message triggers a workflow. If there is a pending workflow for an employee would like to queue the new messages until the
   pending workflow is complete.

Is there any way in cadence to resequence the messages to process them as a group identified by a functional key in the message?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a single workflow per employee which receives a message (possibly with SignalWithStart) and queues it up in a variable if there is already processing going for a message. The processing can be implemented as a child workflow or directly as part of the employee workflow. When the processing is done the new one is kicked off if there is a buffered request. If there are no buffered requests and processing is done the employee workflow can exit.